# pyqt4 event programming (signal and slots )

Tags: pyqt4

I am trying to change this event code to standard signal-slot format. 
But it does not work. 
Can I get help?

this is slide number changing to lcd display number. 
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.lcd = QtGui.QLCDNumber(self)
        self.sld = QtGui.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, self)

        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.lcd)
        vbox.addWidget(self.sld)

        self.setLayout(vbox)
        #sld.valueChanged.connect(lcd.display)

        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.sld, QtCore.SIGNAL(str1), self, QtCore.SLOT("SHOW()"))

        @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
        def SHOW(str1):
            self.lcd.display()


        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Signal & slot')
        self.show()

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You were very close with your first attempt. All you need is:

```
    self.sld.valueChanged.connect(self.lcd.display)
```

(The other lines up to `self.setGeometry` can be deleted).

Comment: thanks ekhumoro, what if I use the "QtCore.QObject.connect(self.sld, QtCore.SIGNAL(str1), self, QtCore.SLOT("SHOW()"))"?   It's new standard 'signal/slot' format, right?

Comment: @sunnylucky. No, that is the [old-style syntax](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/old_style_signals_slots.html), which is not supported at all in PyQt5. You should use the [new-style syntax](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) as shown in my answer.